# Android, ViewClass has leaked window

Tags: java, android, layout, dismiss

i made a small app where i load a new view with **TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY** and now i want to close it by click to a button and i got the error:

```
Activity com.example.viewandbutton.View2Class has leaked window android.widget.RelativeLayout@44957168 that was originally added here
```

i already searched for the error and found out that i have to `dismiss()` the activity but dismiss only works for a *Dialog* object, so i have no idea how to stop the activity.

here is my code:

```
public class View2Class extends Activity {

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.view2);

           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
           View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view2, null);

           WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

           final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
           wm.addView(myView, params);

           Button btnActivity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
           btnActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {   
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                }
            });

        }    
}
```

thanks!

Comment: As per my opinion u need to remove view on stop or on button click:try this `wm.removeView(myView);`

Comment: wm.removeView should be called before finish()

Comment: why are you inflating the same layout again?

Comment: Could you post more of the stacktrace ? Usually, the line that declares the element that's the source of the problem is included

Comment: thanks! yes wm.removeView(myView); worked

Comment: @PareshMayani, i not confident with android java yet, how to you mean that i inflate it two times?

Comment: @PareshMayani because when i remove the setContentView function the ClickListener throws me nullpointerexception

Comment: My mean of inflating layout again is, you are setting view2 layout by using setContentView() and then again inflating the same layout using inflate() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my opinion Remove your `View` on button `onClick()` before the `finish()` like:

```
 btnActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            wm.removeView(myView);
            finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete working code …

```
public class View2Class extends Activity {

    View myView;
    WindowManager wm;

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //setContentView(R.layout.view2);

           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
           myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view2, null);

           WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                           | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                   PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
                   );

           final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
           wm.addView(myView, params);


           Button bb = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
           bb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                wm.removeView(myView);
                    finish();
               }
           });

     }

}
```